# Adding new voices to Text to Speech Engine in Windows 10

Tags: c#, console-application, windows-10, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm developing WPF C# app (not UWP). I utilize speech synthesizer from FCL to get installed voices.So I created a short console application to show installed voices:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using static System.Console;
namespace TTS.Demo
{
    class Voices
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer sp= new SpeechSynthesizer();
            foreach (var vinfo in sp.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                WriteLine(vinfo.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It shows me two installed voices (that are shipped with Windows 10):

[image]

I tried to surf the internet to find out the ability to add natural voices but got quite conflicting answers that I tried with lack of success like registry editing.

Is there any mean to add new voices that runs on Windows 10 (**and tested perhaps**)? If so, I would appreciate if you can direct me to working URLs to voices that I can use in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've written a similar app and was able to get additional voices (such as Hazel) by going to start, settings, region and language, add a language (such as English - United Kingdom). Then click the options for that language and go to speech, and click the download button to get addition tts voices.

I'm sure you can collect more by choosing other languages and downloading the speech from them the same way.